# How to programmatically log in to Azure AD B2C with non-verified domain email?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have a verified domain "contoso.com" in Azure AD and we set up AD B2C so that users can use any email address as their username. I can successfully retrieve a token when I use an email address in the contoso.com domain:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id={appId}' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret={secret}' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid profile email https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/api/app.read' \
--data-urlencode 'username=me@contoso.com' \
--data-urlencode 'password=xxx'
```

However, it doesn't work when I use an account having a different domain (e.g. yopmail.com):

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id={appId}' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret={secret}' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid profile email https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/api/app.read' \
--data-urlencode 'username=me@yopmail.com' \
--data-urlencode 'password=xxx'
```

This returns:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "AADSTS90002: Tenant 'yopmail.com' not found. Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID and are signing into the correct cloud. Check with your subscription administrator, this may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant.\r\nTrace ID: 86cfb501-f233-3333-abfc-e0c6a287bd00\r\nCorrelation ID: feb7d424-35eb-3333-8921-49733610a1c1\r\nTimestamp: 2022-03-08 00:26:08Z",
  "error_codes": [90002]
}
```

I can successfully log in with this email when I run the login user flow and within the app; I just can't figure out how to programmatically log in. Obviously I don't own yopmail.com so I can't make it a verified domain. I want to use this user for my Cypress e2e tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are not using AAD B2C endpoints. You are using AAD endpoints. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow) are AAD B2C docs and endpoints for password grant type.